# Twilio Incoming Call ringing again and again

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have an iOS app where it is configured when a Twilio number receives a call, we get call in the app and also I have setup a webhook to respond to incoming calls and status call-back as well. I am trying to call from INDIAN Number(not a Twilio number) to a Twilio US number and I am getting a call in my iOS app but the problem is that when I do not pick up the call and wait for it end by itself, it starts ringing again until the caller ends the call or the call times out. But when the call is picked up then it works normally and has no issues.

Expected result should be that the call should be ended with no-answer.

When I get the incoming call webhook I am executing the below code:

```
const response = new VoiceResponse();
const dial = response.dial({answerOnBridge: "true"});
const identity = "call_"+req.body.To.split("+")[1];
dial.client(identity)

res.set('Content-type', 'text/xml');
res.status(200).send(response.toString());
```

What I want is that I want to conditionally allow the call to pass through and only pick up the call when the user using iOS app picked up the call or reject the incoming call.